# Validation with Parsley and Modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a problem and can not solve. I have a button that when you click on it displays a message to the user confirmation, it happens that before opening this modal I would like to validate that all fields are filled.

For validation I am using the lib **Parsley**

If I only use simple button as below the validation is successful.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

But if you use the button that calls the modal can not use the validator before.

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#md-default" type="button" id="postar" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <b>Enviar</b></button>


 <!-- Modal -->
                          <div class="modal fade" id="md-default" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                             <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                   <div class="modal-header">
                                      <button type="button " class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="modal-body">
                                      <div class="text-center">
                                         <div class="i-circle primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                                         <div class="confirmacao" id="confirmacao">
                                            <h4>Confirma o envio do Push?</h4>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="resp"></div>
                                         <p></p>
                                      </div>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="modal-footer">
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancelButton" >Cancelar</button>
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat enviar" id="submitButton" >Sim</button>
                                      <button type="button" style="display: none" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal" id = "closeButton">Fechar</button>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.modal-content -->
                             </div>
                             <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                          </div>


<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: you can manually open  the modal after completion of successful validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open modal manually like below:

```
.on('form:submit', function() {
    $('#md-default').modal('show');
    return false;
});
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/thomasnimmi29/pen/amdRyj)

Comment: Nimmi, it validate ok fields! But then he opened the modal, like opening the modal only if all fields are ok.

Comment: I managed, after removing the data-toggle = "modal" worked. Thank you friend

Comment: if you check my codepen link than I think it does it correctly?

Comment: so you solved the problem or it still exist I do not understand what you are asking for :)